# how does one use xlwings UDFs in standalone mode?

Tags: xlwings

i followed the instructions to setup the standalone myproject.xlsm and myproject.py file with the hello UDF inside but the UDF is not loading. How do I get it to load? The documentation only specifies how to load UDFs using the ribbon add-in. There is almost zero reference to how to go about using it in standalone mode.

When I run ImportPythonUDFs sub  i get the following error

[image]
Anyone had any luck in getting UDFs to work in standalone mode?

Comment: You need to Enable Trust access to the VBA project object model under File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings.